# How to login a user in RefineryCMS tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, refinerycms

I'm developing a custom controller in refineryCMS, that placed in the root of the app

```
class ExchangeController < ApplicationController
    def exchange
    end
end
```

It works fine, but to have it tested I need to login a refinery user like this

```
describe "Exchange action" do
   login_refinery_user
   it 'should return a 200' do
    get '/exchange' 
    response.code.should == '200'
   end
end
```

But it just doesn't work :( (undefined local variable or method `login_refinery_user')
Without calling that login method im getting Could not find table 'refinery_roles'

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

For Refinery 2, all that's needed are the following lines in spec/support/devise.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend  ::Refinery::Testing::ControllerMacros::Authentication, :type => :controller
  config.extend  ::Refinery::Testing::RequestMacros::Authentication, :type => :request

end
```

Now "login_refinery_user" will be available along with the other helpers from
https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/testing/lib/refinery/testing/controller_macros/authentication.rb and
https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/testing/lib/refinery/testing/request_macros/authentication.rb

Comment: I have the same issue as Dmitriy, (using Refinery 2.0.9) and sorry to say this does not solve it for me :(

Comment: You need to add this gem to your Gemfile for the Refinery::Testing module to be available: 'refinerycms-testing'

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm doing it with Refinery 1.0.9, it may need to be tweaked for Refinery 2

Create a file named "controller_macros.rb" and place it under spec/support/refinery/

In controller_macros.rb define login_refinery_user

```
module Refinery
  module ControllerMacros
    def login_refinery_user
      before (:each) do
        @refinery_user = Factory(:refinery_user)
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
        sign_in @refinery_user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your factories.rb file be sure you have the following two factories

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "person#{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@cucumber.com" }
  password  "greenandjuicy"
  password_confirmation "greenandjuicy"
end

factory :refinery_user, :parent => :user do
  roles { [ Role[:refinery] ] }

  after_create do |user|
    Refinery::Plugins.registered.each_with_index do |plugin, index|
      user.plugins.create(:name => plugin.name, :position => index)
    end
  end
end
```

In your spec_helper.rb file include the controller macros module into your controller tests, and also make sure you have the Devise test helpers

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ::Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend  ::Refinery::ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: I used this workaround cause installing Refinery::Testing caused too many gem conflicts. I made some small changes to get it going like namespacing `Role` and pointing the `:refinery_user` factory at the class is belongs to. Thanks SupaIrish. https://gist.github.com/nulty/6c6a190edc0cd10562fb

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is to make sure you add your plugin/engine name to the list of plugins the currently logged in user is allowed to access:

```
refinery_login_with :refinery_user 

before do
  logged_in_user.plugins = logged_in_user.plugins | %w(<plugin name>)
end
```