# How to get feature spec login helpers in Refinery CMS up and running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, refinerycms

I want to use `login_refinery_user`-helper methods for my refinery feature specs. I added the following to `spec/support/devise.rb` according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926783/5941617

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend  ::Refinery::Testing::ControllerMacros::Authentication, :type => :controller
  config.extend  ::Refinery::Testing::RequestMacros::Authentication, :type => :request
end
```

Unfortunately my specs cannot find the requested methods. I cannot find the method either, even `Refinery::Testing::RequestMacros` is not present, although it should be according to https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/testing/lib/refinery/testing/request_macros/authentication.rb

Does someone know what needs to be done in order to enable the proper helpers?

> `gem list | ack refinery`
>
> refinerycms (4.0.2)
>
> refinerycms-authentication-devise (2.0.0)
>
> refinerycms-core (4.0.2)
>
> refinerycms-dragonfly (1.0.0)
>
> refinerycms-testing (4.0.2)
>
> ...

best,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the helpers into the correct type of tests. Since you mentioned feature tests you probably need

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :feature
  ...
end
```